# How to remove the whitespaces between Table and paragraph?

Tags: tables, white-space

I am writing a report using latex on overleaf. After a paragraph I want to add a table:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Two Object Detection Types}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \hline
        % \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
        % \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Types of Object Detection Detectors}} \\ \hline
        % \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\ul \textbf{One Stage Detectors}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\ul \textbf{Two Stage Detectors}}} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Single Shot Detector} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RCNN family} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{YOLO v1-v4} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CenterNet} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Scaled YOLO v4} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{EfficientDet} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have used [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) website to generate the code.

But I have a paragraph before this table and there are whitespaces in between as shown in the figure below. I would like to know how do I remove them whitespace.
[image]

Not only that but I am also getting the error: Undefined Control Sequence for the second and third multicolumn lines in the above code. Can someone explain to me why this is and how it can be resolved?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

[image]

Comment: In order to help you you should show an emc. Please read carefully this page: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952. The "Undefined Control Sequence" error will disappear if you you load all the necessary packages: multicol, soul, xcolor, colortbl

Comment: Additionally `\begin{table}[]` should probably be `\begin{table}[htbp]` just in case. BTW: from where do to have that using `\ul` here is a good idea?

Comment: emc? Also I have included the packages as mentioned on the website from which I converted the excel table to latex: % \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
% \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}

Comment: I have solved it. I forgot to add [H] after \begin{table}. Apologies. Can I post this as an answer?

Comment: you would get much simpler code if you simply hand wrote the table, that site comes up quite offten always with massively over-complicated code with redundant \multicolumn everywhere

Comment: Oh okay okay. I thought using the site might reduce my work load but it turned out to be the opposite. Thanks for your help and will keep this in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing *very* wrong with the table except the command `\ul` that must be defined or be provided by a package, that must be loaded.

For underline the first bold faced row (an overkill) you might use the package `soul` and its command `\ul`. The correct use for a bold underline  is
`\textbf{\ul{One Stage Detectors}}`.

You don't need all the complicated `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{..` for such a simple table. They are artifacts from the table generator.

What is needed is to add vertical space in the first row to accommodate the underline.  Done with `mutirow`, making  the first row two rows high.

And do not use `[H]`. Use `[h!]` instead.

Next time please provide the complete  MWE with its preamble.

[image: w]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text    
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{soul} % underlines
\usepackage{multirow}   % multiple rows

\begin{document}
    
1.  \kant[1]

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \sffamily
        \centering
        \caption{Two Object Detection Types}    
        \smallskip  
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline  
        \cellcolor{gray!10}  &\cellcolor{gray!10}\\
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{gray!10}\textbf{\ul{One Stage Detectors}}}& 
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{gray!10}\textbf{\ul{Two Stage Detectors}}}\\
        \hline
        Single Shot Detector    & mRCNN family  \\ \hline
        YOLO v1-v4              & CenterNet     \\ \hline
        Scaled YOLO v4          & EfficientDet  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

2.  \kant[2]    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand now thank you. But the Column headings "One stage Detectors" and "Two Stage Detectors" are not centered as can be seen in Edit 1 of the question. And I have included all the necessary packages in the preamble.

Comment: @duddal  Please see the updated answer.